# C#: Excel: set selected workseet for next workbook-opening

Tags: c#, excel, select, worksheet

I want to select a worksheet that should be the selected worksheet when I open the workbook the next time. I've already tried the ".Activate()" and the ".Select()" method of the worksheet but it doesn't work.

How can I do this with the Excel interop assembly in C#?

Regards
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to select the sheet from inside of an Excel COM-addin.

First you need a place to store the name of the Worksheet that needs to be selected.
A possible place that's not directly visible to the user is in `Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties`.

Second you need to read this `DocumentProperty` the next time and activate the Worksheet when the Workbook is opened. This can be done in the `void OnStartupComplete(ref Array custom)` if there is already an `_application.ActiveWorkbook` and additionally in the EventHandler of `_application.WorkbookOpen += wb => { ... };` if Excel is already running.

(`_application.WorkbookOpen` is not always called when you open a Workbook without Excel already running, so you have to activate it in the `OnStartupComplete` too.)

To effectively select the sheet you have to call `Workbook.Activate()` first and then call `Worksheet.Activate()`. If you don't activate the Workbook before the Worksheet it won't work most of the time. Additionally it could be useful to select the first cell of the sheet calling `ws.Cells[1, 1].Select()`.

If you are inside a COM-addin then you get the `_application` from the first parameter of `void OnConnection(object application, ...)`. You just need to cast it to `_application = application as Application;`.

If you are inside a VSTO-addin you can get the Application from `Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application`.

The only drawback (that I know of) is: You can't select a sheet if you are in an Excel-addin (not a COM-addin) that only exports UDFs to Excel because this type of addin has no permission to do so.